# INNER JOIN performance with '<' or '>' condition

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, inner-join

I have two tables with the column `SessionOrder`. This column is an integer datatype and have the following index: `CREATE INDEX OSIDX_<internal name> ON <Entity>`.

I'm executing the following query:

```
SELECT i_0.rn, i_1.rn 
FROM (
    SELECT "RawEvent"."SessionOrder" as rn
    FROM "RawEvent" i_0
    WHERE something = 12
)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT "RawEvent"."SessionOrder" as rn
    FROM "RawEvent" i_1
    WHERE something = 14
) ON i_0.rn > i_1.rn
```

The problem of this query is the `ON i_0.rn > i_1.rn` that gets too slow and times out. 
I replaced it by `ON i_0.rn = i_1.rn` and it was very fast but obviously does not produce the expected results.

Does someone know a way to increase the performance of this query avoiding the timeout?
Other goal of this question is to understand why it gets bad performance with `ON i_0.rn > i_1.rn`.

PS: It is not possible to increase the timeout time

Comment: What does the execution plan show it's doing? How many rows does each subquery find? (Why are you using subqueries rather than just joining the tables? And this doesn't look like Oracle syntax at the moment).

Comment: This is not a valid query. The tables' aliases are not defined in the scope of `ON i_0.rn > i_1.rn`

Comment: I agree with Alex, this definitely s not Oracle syntax. That said, this is almost a cartesian join. Are you really intending to join every row less than i_o.rn to i_o? As an example, this SQL returns 4,950 rows: with aset as ( select rownum r from dba_objects where rownum < 101)
select a.r, b.r from aset a
inner join aset b on a.r > b.r.

Comment: This kind of join is always going to be expensive. If these tables are very large at all, the result might be so large that it's not worth trying to make this work. For instance, if both sub-queries return only 1000 rows with identical sets of `SessionOrder`, then your result set is going to be 499,500 rows. I'd suggest looking for a better way of solving the underlying problem.

Comment: I force switch from `Oracle` tag to `SQL-Server`, please change back if you're sure it's oracle (but this syntax don't look oracle at all...)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that this is ´ORACLE´, but this query goes to a pre-processor. The subqueries can find several rows (26.000 each one).

Comment: @HélderGonçalves 26k rows for each query will result in ~288 M (26k * 26k / 2) rows in your result set (assuming both queries return the same set of SessionOrder values). That doesn't sound sensible.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I think that for some reason it is not using the  indexes.

Answer (score 4):

Please check first if you realy use Oracle database. The syntax of your SQL suggest either other RDBMS or some prepocessor.

To get an impression what you can expect from such kind of queries, you may use a dummy example as follows.

**Generate Sample Data**

```
create table myTab as 
with mySeq as 
(select rownum SessionOrder from dual connect by level <= 10000)
select 12 something, SessionOrder from mySeq union all
select 14  something, SessionOrder from mySeq
;
```

This produces both subsources each with 10.000 sequences starting from 1 to 10.000.

**Test Query**

```
create table myRes as
select a.SessionOrder rn0, b.SessionOrder rn1
from myTab a join myTab b on a.SessionOrder > b.SessionOrder and
a.something = 12 and b.something = 14;
```

Produces 49.995.000 rows in less that 30 seconds.

*If you expect to get such large result in much less time, you'll need an advanced optimization*. Without knowing your data and requirement no generll advice is possible.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended I tried to solve the problem with other strategy that got greater performance.

Despite this simple solution, I do not understand why the original query got too slow. I think that the Oracle engine is not using indexes.

```
SELECT i_0."SessionOrder",  i_1."SessionOrder"
FROM "RawEvent" i_0
INNER JOIN "RawEvent" i_1 ON  i_0."SessionOrder" < i_1."SessionOrder" 
WHERE i_0."something" = 12 AND i_1."something" = 14
```

Comment: That query doesn't return the same results as your original one - you'll have to replace `OR` with `AND` to get the same results. Also, without additional information about your input data (row count, distribution of something / SessionOrder), it's impossible to tell whether it would make any difference if the optimizer used the index. It might very well decide that a full table scan is more appropriate if your data is heavily skewed.

Answer (score 0):

Your query performs three tasks:

1) fetch the data for both subsets (12 and 14)

2) join the data  and

3) pass the result to the client

Note that the index access (that you suspects to cause problems) is relevant only for the step 1.
So to get a better impression the first thing is to realize the distribution of the time elapsed between the three steps.
This can be done using SQL*Plus (I'm using the same generated data as in my previous answer)

**Data Access**

As my table has no index, performing a count(*) performs a FULL TABLE SCAN. So in a worst case a twice of the time is used to get the data.

```
SQL> set timi on
SQL> set autotrace on
SQL> select count(*) from mytab;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     20000

Elapsed: 00:00:01.13

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3284627250

--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name  | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |       |     1 |  5472   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |       |     1 |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| MYTAB | 20000 |  5472   (1)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*The FTS is ready in about a one second, so to get both groups aprox. two seconds are elapsed.*

**JOIN**

The elapsed time for join can by simulated with a CTAS of the join query.

```
SQL> create table myRes as
  2  select a.SessionOrder rn0, b.SessionOrder rn1
  3  from myTab a join myTab b on a.SessionOrder > b.SessionOrder and
  4  a.something = 12 and b.something = 14;

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:23.65
```

*Join returns nearly 50M rows (due to greater than condition) and take about 21 seconds (I subtract 2 seconds for the data access).*

**PASS the Data to Client**

We use the option `set autotrace traceonly` to suppress the output of the query on the client screen, but the data is transferred, so we can 
measure the time. (If you render the result on the screen, the time will be even much higher)

```
SQL> SET ARRAYSIZE 5000
SQL> set autotrace traceonly
SQL> select a.SessionOrder rn0, b.SessionOrder rn1
  2  from myTab a join myTab b on a.SessionOrder > b.SessionOrder and
  3  a.something = 12 and b.something = 14;

49995000 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:03:03.89

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2857240533

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |       |    49M|   667M| 11077   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN         |       |    49M|   667M| 11077   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   SORT JOIN         |       | 10000 | 70000 |  5473   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| MYTAB | 10000 | 70000 |  5472   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   SORT JOIN         |       | 10000 | 70000 |  5473   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| MYTAB | 10000 | 70000 |  5472   (1)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*Here is the most time spend about 2:40 minutes*

**Summary**

So in the scenario from a total 3 minutes+ only about 2 seconds are spend on data access (or about 1%).
Even if you cut the data access to a tenth - you'll see virtually no difference.
The problem lies in the join and even more in the transfer of the data to the client.

**When Index Can Help**

And of course it depends...

In a very special case, where you have a very large table with very little data with `something in (12,14)`
you may profit from index defined on something **AND** SessionOrder. This allows to use *index only* access to data bypassing table access at all.